# Ground wires absent from circuits exiting apartment panel

Tags: electrical-panel, grounding, subpanel

I'm taking a look at the (only) panel in my apartment (7 apartments in building, NYC) and I'm noticing that out of all the circuits leaving the panel, not a single one of them contains a ground wire. Only hot(s) and neutral. On closer inspection I can see the ground wire coming in through the top, it connects to the ground bar, but there are no other wires attached to the ground bar.
The 120v circuits leave the panel with just a hot and a neutral and the 240v circuits exit in bunches of 2 hot and 1 neutral.

Are all these circuits ungrounded? Is it likely or possible that these circuits get their ground from somewhere else that is not the panel in my apartment? Are these circuits meeting up with ground each on their own somewhere on the way to the outlets or is it another common point?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image: Ground bar]
[image: Ground bar]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please take a picture of the innards of your panel so we can better assist you.  Also, if wires are in metal conduit, that serves as a proper grounding method.  Also, where are you, it helps bc people are more aware of local codes.   BTW, what made you decide to open up the panel and inspect?  Are you having issues?

Comment: Is your house wired in conduit by any chance?  The conduit itself is a valid ground conductor, so in that case there won't be any actual ground wires, but everything will still be grounded.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the panel please, especially ones that show where the various bunches leave the panel at?

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson, photos added. It is difficult to see above the panel through the crack in the drywall for me to know the presence/absence of conduit. The apartment is in NYC. I am not having any issues. I decided to go back to school and just started a residential electrician course and I was curious about the state of my own panel.

Comment: There's a lot of paper on those wires. doesn't look like conduit but is probably BX  with some duplex connectors.  What type of outlets do you have?

Comment: Can you get a photo in that small gap above the panel it must be a metal flex, but the type may be apparent if a clear shot through that gap. Conduit is regularly used in larger / commercial, industrial buildings as the equipment ground, another identification of this method is metal boxes at the receptacles and switches.

Comment: That's an awesomely great set of photos - thank you.

Comment: That work is so beautifully done that if I was an electrical inspector, and I saw something in this panel that didn't meet code, I'd assume that the panel was correct and I was misreading the code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Your building is most likely wired using armored cable (Type AC), so it's grounded, alright

Given the presence of per-conductor paper packing protruding into the panel through the cable connectors, the *lack* of cable *jacketing* protruding into the panel through the same route, the lack of ground wires, the vintage of the panel and apparent vintage of the wiring (rather new), and the context of the building and its locale and use (apartment in NYC), my most likely guess as to the wiring method used in your building would be "new style" Type AC (armored cable).  This cable uses the metal armor in conjunction with a thin aluminum bonding strip as the grounding path; the metal cable armor provides a low-resistance path generally, while the bonding strip shorts adjacent turns of the spiral-wound armor to each other to avoid any potential for "choking" of fault currents.  (Very old BX lacked that bonding strip, and there have been various tales of BX armor overheating under low, sustained fault current conditions as a result of the "choke" effect not allowing enough fault current to pass to trip the breaker.)

### As an aside: whoever wired that panel was proud of their work, and for the most part deservedly so, so you might as well take this learning opportunity

As an aside, what you are looking at here is a panel that's been quite neatly and professionally wired, by and large.  About the only thing I cannot see in your pictures are the anti-short "redhead" bushings on the connectors. Otherwise, the feeder to this panel looks to be a proper four-wire feed with the panel's bonding screw pulled, as is proper for a subpanel (if this was a main panel, the bonding screw would sit in that "notch" in the top right of the neutral bar).  Furthermore, the branch circuit wiring was done in a very tidy fashion, looping down along the side gutters and back up to the breaker and neutral lugs/screws to provide excess length in case a rearrangement is called for, and all the wiring's been neatly tagged with what circuit it goes to.  Finally, note that all the white wires used as hots in 240V-only circuits, as well as the B leg of the incoming feeder, have been wrapped with red *phase tape* to prevent confusion.

Best of luck and wishes for your schooling!

Comment: Agreed, beautiful job in the panel. I dk why there are so many wire nutted connections in the panel, but other than that, it looks great. Also appreciate copper mains rather than AL.   +

Comment: If you zoom in, it sure looks like there’s plenty of NM-B jacket present, just trimmed short. There are also up to three black/white pairs coming in a single knockout, which doesn’t make sense for AC.

Comment: I agree, probably armored cable. A great job on the panel. +1

Comment: Amazing answer! I tried to get a pic in between the drywall crack but none were any good. Are the armored cables and aluminum bonding strip connected to the ground bar in the panel, or the water pipes, or a ground rod or something? Or is the armored cable itself the only source of ground?

Comment: @nobody -- all I see is the paper wrap, and NYC AIUI doesn't permit NM anyway; also, duplex AC connectors are a thing

Comment: @natsuki_2002 -- they're connected to the panel cabinet itself, which is metal, and connected to the ground bar

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Got it, and on the outlet side in the rooms, the ground wire coming out of a light fixture would be connected to the outlet box, which is connected to armor of the AC?

Comment: @natsuki_2002 -- yes, that'll be how it works :)

Comment: @nobody -- also, the paper wrap in NM is directly under the jacket, covering all the conductors, while the paper wraps in AC/BX cover each conductor individually